# Monitoring gitlab version with icinga2

Tags: gitlab, icinga2

I'd like to monitor the version of docker gitlab-ce instances with icinga2. I did not find a plugin for that. I began writing my own (which I am glad to share after finishing). Maybe I oversaw a very basic thing and there are other ways being notified when a newer version comes up. I compare the version of my gitlab (through api) with the latest version tag on gitlab-foss.